# ¿Montar aplicación que busque actualizaciones Online?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-forms, windows-installer

Tengo una aplicación de windows form en C#, quiero publicarla ahora, es decir, hacer su instalador, pero necesito hacerlo de tal forma que la aplicación se pueda actualizar automáticamente, algo así como la aplicación de escritorio de GITHub que busca actualizaciones e informa cuando hay una para descargarla, sin necesidad de ir hasta la página, descargar un nuevo instalador, desinstalar el programa actual y volver a instalar, eso es lo que específicamente no quisiera que tuviera que hacer el usuario que instale mi aplicacion.

¿Cómo se hacer eso?, ya tengo una IP (intranet) para montarla y que los usuarios y la aplicación puedan apuntar allí (sería el servidor).

Estoy intentando hacer algo con `ClickOnce` pero me aparece este error, no sé si es alguna falla de configuración o algo similar:

```
ESTADO DE PROGRESO DE LA OPERACIÓN
    * [14/06/2017 10:07:27 a.m.] : Se ha iniciado la activación de C:\Users\fmontoya\Downloads\AssistLogin.application.
    * [14/06/2017 10:07:27 a.m.] : El procesamiento del manifiesto de la implementación finalizó correctamente.
    * [14/06/2017 10:07:27 a.m.] : Se ha iniciado la instalación de la aplicación.

DETALLES DEL ERROR
    Se detectaron los siguientes errores durante esta operación.
    * [14/06/2017 10:07:27 a.m.] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (Zone)
        - La implementación y la aplicación no tienen zonas de seguridad coincidentes.
        - Origen: System.Deployment
        - Seguimiento de la pila:
            en System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            en System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            en System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            en System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            en System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            en System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

DETALLES DE TRANSACCIÓN DEL ALMACÉN DE COMPONENTES
    No hay información disponible sobre la transacción.
```

Como vieron lo solucioné de cierta manera, pero tengo un fallo, la aplicación debo ejecutarla luego mediante otra app, pero no lo puedo hacer, porque al usar clickOnce me genera una ruta de acceso diferente cada vez y no tengo como saberla, además, no puedo modificar la ruta donde se instale, eso es un gran fallo para mi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo solucioné de la siguiente manera:

En el clicOnce lo configuré que creará el instalador en una carpeta en mi equipo local y que fuera un Cd-Rom DVD.
Luego, en si esta aplicación buscará actualizaciones le dí que sí y coloque una ruta de una carpeta compartida en la intranet.

En la ruta que coloque, cada vez que genero una nueva publicación en mi equipo, la pego en esa carpeta y doy Si a todas la advertencias de reemplazo y todo y listo, la aplicación ya me genera un informe de si hay o no una nueva versión.

[Solución Temporal]

Answer (score 1):

creo que lo que estás pidiendo es realizar un despliegue usando [ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/t71a733d.aspx).

Comment: Si exacto, pero no lo puedo hacer, y no he encontrado un manual o tutorial que me funcione para lograr hacerlo :/

Comment: esto es mas un comentario que una respuesta..

Comment: Ya logré solucionarlo